# Create a URI Scheme Handler Association

Tags: windows, java, windows-registry, uri

I am new to creating Custom URI Schemes and I am trying to launch an executable jar file using URI Schemes in my Windows 7 system.

For running this jar file from command prompt, I use this command:

`java -jar demo.jar`

**EDIT:**

For launching the same using the Custom URI Scheme, I created a `.reg` file with the below entry (**Copied from the below post**):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DemoStart]
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DemoStart\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DemoStart\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DemoStart\shell\open\command]
@="\"java.exe\" -jar \"C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\demo.jar\""
```

This does not works for the following reason:

The executable jar file which I am trying the run named `demo.jar` is a third party provided jar file and it has quite a few dependencies on XML config files which are also located in the same folder containing the jar file. I don't have privilege to change any code present within the jar file.

Using command prompt, the command `"java.exe" -jar "demo.jar"` works only when I navigate to the folder containing both the `demo.jar` as well as the `dependent config xml files`. BUT if I try to run the command: `"java.exe" -jar "C:\Users\John\Desktop\demo.jar"` from the default location of the command prompt window (which in my case is `C:\Users\John`) then the command does not work since the dependent config xml files are not available.

Hence I need to find out a way of changing the default location of the command prompt as well before executing the jar file.

Please suggest whether it is possible to set the command prompt default location to `C:\Users\John\Desktop` when I trigger the custom URI (In that case no need to navigate to a different location and the command should work fine).

Comment: I created a `.txt` file, changed the file extension to `.reg`, put the code you posted below and then double clicked the `.reg` file to create the registry entry. Then I verified the same in the `regedit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.reg` file doesn't look right. The format is very odd. It should look something more like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DemoStart]
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DemoStart\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DemoStart\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DemoStart\shell\open\command]
@="\"java.exe\" -jar \"C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\demo.jar\""
```

If this *still* doesn't work, double check that java is in your PATH. If it is, and it ***still*** doesn't work, try replacing "java" with the full path to the Java exe.

Comment: That cannot work either because the URL is never passed to the program. `"%1"` should appear at the appropriate location. Also, always use absolute paths, otherwise you’re just asking for trouble. /edit: Oh yeah, and it might also be prudent to specify a name (`@` next to `URL Protocol`).

Comment: That’s not what I meant. I was referring to the “friendly name”. It’s the default entry *next to* `URL Protocol`. You can see it in most entries in `HKCR`. I’ll post an answer of my own later.

Comment: @Izam +1 for the help so far. When I open the `command prompt`, the default location is `C:\Users\John`. If I manually navigate to the location `C:\Users\John\Desktop` in the command prompt and run the command `"java.exe" -jar "demo.jar"` then it works fine. But if I don't navigate to the `Desktop` and run this command `"java.exe" -jar "C:\Users\John\Desktop\demo.jar"` from the default location (i.e. `C:\Users\John`) then it does not work since in Desktop I have some other XML files as well needed to run the jar file.

Comment: Ok I did some application related changes and finally got this thing working, hence accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, from what I gather your main problem isn’t the actual file association but the working directory. Unfortunately, the working directory cannot be influenced when launched from a file association. If a program depends on files beside its executable, it would be broken by design were it to rely on the working directory.

Fortunately, programming isn’t just for experts anymore. ;)

The following single-line [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) script (which can be compiled to a standalone `.exe` file) launches a program (or `.jar` file or whatever). The working directory will be set to the script `.exe` location.

```
Run, hello.jar, %A_ScriptDir%
```

I haven’t actually tested this with a `.jar` file, because I don’t have JDK installed right now. I did try with an uncompiled AutoHotkey script though. Documentation on the `Run` command is available [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm).

Comment: I followed these steps: Created a `.ahk` file, added the entry `#z::Run, demp.jar, %A_ScriptDir%` in the file, `Run Script` and then click `Windows Key + z` to start the `demo.jar`, all these worked fine for me. But I don't want to ask my users to click the `AutoHot Key` manually, hence willing to automate this process to something like: When the browser starts, then the `demo.jar` is executed automatically. Please suggest something on this.

Comment: You’ll have to associate the AHK script (or `.exe`) with the protocol, instead of `java.exe`.